# Unreliable Marshal when Converting Int to String Depending on Framework

Tags: c#, string, marshalling, native

I am using the following line to convert my `WTS_PROCESS_INFO` object's `ProcessName` property to a string:

`string name = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(processInfos[I].processName)`

This seems to be quite reliable, and all the process names are successfully converted.

However, if I make this same call **after** passing `WTS_PROCESS_INFO` to another class and method, each attempt at converting to a string results in `""` apart from the first attempt.

This only is only happening when using `.NET-3.5` but seems to work fine in `.NET-4.0`

**Example:**

**Working** - each name is converted to the correct string before passing the entire list.

```
    public static List<Proc> WTSEnumerateProcesses(string servername)
    {
        IntPtr pProcessInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        int processCount = 0;
        var hServer = OpenServer(servername);

        if (!Native.WTSEnumerateProcesses(hServer, 0, 1, ref pProcessInfo, ref processCount))
            return null;

        IntPtr pMemory = pProcessInfo;
        WTS_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfos = new WTS_PROCESS_INFO[processCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < processCount; i++)
        {
            processInfos[i] = (WTS_PROCESS_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pProcessInfo, typeof(WTS_PROCESS_INFO));
            pProcessInfo = (IntPtr)((int)pProcessInfo + Marshal.SizeOf(processInfos[i]));
        }

        List<Proc> asd = new List<Proc>();
        foreach (var item in processInfos)
        {
            if (item.SessionID == 5)
            {
                string procname = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(item.ProcessName);
                var proc = new Proc(servername, 5, item.SessionID, procname);
                asd.Add(proc);
            }
        }

        Native.WTSFreeMemory(pMemory);
        return asd;
    }
```

**Not working** - the conversions which take place after passing the `WTS_PROCESS_INFO`s out result in empty strings (apart from the first one).

```
    public static WTS_PROCESS_INFO[] WTSEnumerateProcesses(string servername)
    {
        IntPtr pProcessInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        int processCount = 0;
        var hServer = OpenServer(servername);

        if (!Native.WTSEnumerateProcesses(hServer, 0, 1, ref pProcessInfo, ref processCount))
            return null;

        IntPtr pMemory = pProcessInfo;
        WTS_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfos = new WTS_PROCESS_INFO[processCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < processCount; i++)
        {
            processInfos[i] = (WTS_PROCESS_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pProcessInfo, typeof(WTS_PROCESS_INFO));
            pProcessInfo = (IntPtr)((int)pProcessInfo + Marshal.SizeOf(processInfos[i]));
        }

        Native.WTSFreeMemory(pMemory);
        return processInfos;
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling `Native.WTSFreeMemory(pMemory);` that is freeing the memory associated with the strings. This call is freeing both the `pMemory` that is an array of `WTS_PROCESS_INFO` AND the memory pointed from the various `pProcessName`. So the solution is to copy somewhere those strings BEFORE calling `Native.WTSFreeMemory(pMemory);`

Comment: Aaah, thank you xanatos! Would you say that it is good practice to call this here, or should I just do what works and free the memory later?

Comment: @Bassie You have to free it in the method, because only inside the method you have the `pMemory` pointer. My suggestion is to create a `MyWtsProcessInfo` (having a `string processName`), copy the data from the `processInfos[i]` to this new class and free the `pMemory`.